# Create solid background bitmap efficiently

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I think I read all of the answers on SO regarding bitmaps and memory problems, but couldn't find a solution to my problem:

I am creating four solid background bitmaps and draw some text on them (see code below) using Bitmap.createBitmap. The problem is that on some devices with low memory, I get a OutOfMemoryException, as the bitmaps take more than 30MB on the heap. Which I think is pretty much for just solid color and some text. I recycle the bitmaps properly when not needed any more but I need to have 4 of them in memory.

My question: Is there a way to reduce the memory consumption of these bitmaps?
I tried reducing the width and height in createBitmap, but then the text size is not right any more. I also tried compressing the image like this after creating it:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, out);
Bitmap decoded = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
```

but that does not decrease the heap size at all.

---

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
bitmap.eraseColor(mColor);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, paint);
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
paint.setTypeface(FontManager.getTypefaceGeogrotesqueMedium());

float fontSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 55, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
float fontSizeReason = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

paint.setTextSize(fontSize);

int margin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 100, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
int distance = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 20, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

float xPos = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
float yPos = (canvas.getHeight() - distance) / 2;
canvas.drawText((String) TextUtils.ellipsize(mText, paint, canvas.getWidth() - margin, TextUtils.TruncateAt.END), xPos, yPos, paint);

yPos -= paint.ascent() + paint.descent();
yPos += distance;
paint.setTypeface(FontManager.getTypefaceGeogrotesqueRegular());
canvas.drawText((String) TextUtils.ellipsize(mOtherText, paint, canvas.getWidth() - margin, TextUtils.TruncateAt.END), xPos, yPos, paint);
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: Are you certain that you need bitmaps? You can just draw a color onto the canvas and then draw text onto it. You could make custom views and edit their onDraw to make it easier.

Comment: I need not only to draw the text but to punch it through the background, so you can see the view under it. The only method I know of to do that is with a bitmap like above. If you know a method for that without a bitmap, let me know.

Comment: how do you use your Bitmap after its created and filled?  what is it for?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is... gorgeous. But! The question is: `is it worth the effort`? or you can just live with a simpler but effective UI as well?

Comment: it's set as an ImageBitmap on an ImageView

Comment: @Der Golem: no, I can't :-)

Comment: so use a Drawable,  not Bitmap

Comment: So, maybe you could use an **SVG** file (vector graphics = lighter than pixel graphics)?

Comment: @pskink: how can I do it with a drawable?

Comment: ImageView#setImageDrawable(yourDrawable)

Comment: I know how to set an ImageDrawable to an imageView, but how can I create an ImageDrawable in code, set a solid background and punch text through it?

Comment: class MySolidBackgroundDrawableWithText extends Drawable { ...